# Reputation is not being updated

Tags: support, reputation

This [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323687/what-is-a-biological-only-father-called)  got me 11 up votes but the reputation was not added. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a maximum of 200 points a day (UTC 0000-2359), excluding accepts which give you 15 points and bounties that are not subject to the daily rep cap. Congratulations!

Comment: That is just.... well, whst can I do. Thanks. I'm relieved now

Comment: @vickyace don't worry, keep posting such good answers. :)

Comment: When does that 24 hour period begin and when does it end?